# Error in if: (condition) ? true : false;

Tags: php

I am currenctly busy developing a precalculus course. I want to make a dropdown question. This is already a build function.
I want the student to select if the amount of degrees equals rads.

I have the following:

```
$a=[30,45,60,90]
(degrees)

$b=[30,45,60,90]

$c=pi()/(180*$b)

$d=pi()*$a/180

$e=($c==$d)? true : false;
```

The system tells me:
Error: Incorrect syntax in ($c = $d) ? true : false; in definition:($c = $d) ? 'true' : 'false';

I'm new to this, and can't find a solution...
System accepts maxima, php, latex.

Comment: IS THAT THE ACTUAL CODE? `$c=$d` SHOULD BE `$c==$d` OR `$c===$d`

Comment: COBOL developer b0s3 ? :p

Comment: @b0s3 , mistyped my code. it is $c == $d , still gives me an error.
The platform the company uses has build in variables.

Comment: @lilienfa If it is the actual code then you are missing semicolons  `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the semicolon in the end.
After removing the ";" in the end, the problem got solved... One platform.
Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me out!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should make your own answer 'accepted' for future reference

Comment: How do i do that? Just made an account:)

Comment: Just figured out you have to wait 48hrs to do so http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/ :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if you want to check equality then you have to use == instead of =.

so your code be like `$e=($c==$d)? true : false;`

Answer (score 0):

With a single '=' you are assigning the value in $d to $c. Your ternary operation, `(condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)`, requires the left side of the '?' to return a boolean value, hence you must to do `$c == $d` which checks for equality and returns a boolean.

Comment: @lilienfa Well, there are a lot of syntax errors in your code. Did you write it from memory or did you copy/paste? PHP requires you to end all lines with ';', e.g. `$c=pi()/(180*$b);`. Also, this won't work: `$a/180`. You can't divide an array with a number, you most likely meant to do something like this: `$a[$index]/180`

Comment: That is the complicated thing. Since the variables are build into the platform, i don't need to write a ; in the end.
As for the array, in the platform, the [...] is a list of random values. The system selects those values randomly. We don't work with indices.

Comment: @lilienfa and what about this `$a/180` and this `(180*$b)`? Are these legal operations?

Comment: ah, I see .. so in this maxima system you can actually write stuff like `180*[30,45,60,90]`, which multiplies a vector by a scalar.

Comment: Yes true, but:
1 degree = (2*pi())/360 if we divide both nominator and denominator with a 2, we get: (pi()/180). So if we want 90 degreed we do 90*(pi()/180).
Might be that I am totally wrong. But this is what I'm aiming for:

(90*(pi()/180) == 90*(pi()/180))? true: false;
in this case it would be true.
Therefore, if the student clicks true in dropdown, it would be correct.

The system doesnt accept degrees...
So assume that the left 90 is from $a en the 90 on the right is $b.

That's what I am trying to achieve... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

`$e=($c=$d)? true : false;`

Must be :

```
$e=($c==$d)? true : false; or `$e=($c===$d)? true : false;`
```